# (301 Redirect) .htaccess Including Queries and Wildcard Subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to move a site (built in codeigniter) from an old domain to a new one. Ideally, we'd like to forward on the url scheme, in case a user has an old bookmark. I have found the code to append query strings with the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.new_site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

But our url structure uses 'subdirectories' (passing a controller name to the index.php), so a typical url looks like:

```
http://website.com/controller/method/param1/param2
```

How can I set up the .htaccess to forward on the the subdirectories as well?

```
http://website.com/controller/method/param1/param2
http://new_website.com/controller/method/param1/param2
```

Comment: So what's the old link look like?

Comment: http://website.com/controller/method/param1/param2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! Adding the `$` to the end of the rewrite rule `^(.*)` allows you to pull in all the directories with the redirect. Hope that helps someone!

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_website.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```